# Slack API and OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, api, oauth, slack-api, slack

I am currently trying to develop an application in C# using the SlackConnector library. [SlackConnector](https://github.com/noobot/SlackConnector)

The application would receive and send messages to slack channels and DM. (I am successfully able to send and receive messages from my slack using the test token generator.) [TEST TOKEN GENERATOR](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-test-tokens)

The thing I dont understand is how is it possible for the user who will use the app to give full authorization to access their Slack account and so from there on they can send and receive messages likewise.

Is [OAuth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) something that I need to use ? I created a slack app and followed steps to get access token from users but the access tokens for some reason do not establish a connection, like the test tokens do ? I suppose with that token you can post messages on behalf of user only not receive messages have only limited access, not sure !!

Is there a way to programmatically get a signed-in users generated test-token? or a way that the user can give my desktop application full access to the slack account without having to generate a test token manually?

Even if I were to go to production with only me as a user what access token would I use the same Test Token ? Isn't it only for testing where is the actual token ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer a few of your questions here:

Yes, you'll need to use OAuth 2.0 and a Slack app to offer your integration for installation on other Slack teams.

Yes, test tokens are just meant for developing against one team. They represent the full capabilities of whichever account created it, within the context of the team it was created on.

To connect to the RTM API and to read and write DMs, you'll need to make a few decisions about which [OAuth scopes](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) you'll want to request, and whether you're wanting to operate from the perspective of your application as a kind of "bot user" within a channel, or from the perspective of the user using your app. Generally, apps operate from their own perspective.

The most common way an app like this is built is by asking for the `bot` OAuth scope, which grants a package of permissions. The tricky part is that the bot permissions aren't granted to the top-level `token` at the end of the OAuth flow -- they're granted to the `bot_user_token` you'll find under the `bot` part of the response hash. Using that token will let you connect to the RTM API and interact via direct messages with team members. (See the [bot user](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) docs for info about "Tokens and scopes".

If your intent is to operate directly on behalf of a user (posting and responding to messages as if you were the user authorizing your app), then you need to ask for very distinct OAuth scopes that will be applied to the top-level user `token` in the final OAuth response.

Comment: Thanks for your response, You are mentioning other teams, everyone using my application will be on the same team. And I want to operate from the perspective of the user not bots. Is there a any documentation where I can find more information on OAuth Scopes besides the slack documentation ?

Comment: The docs are probably still best. The best approach is to go to each API method that performs the actions you want to take and note which OAuth scope it indicates is required. Then ask for those named OAuth scopes as users in your team install the app. If you don't mind and your team don't a broader set of capabilities (maybe even too many), you might ask for the `client` scope as a kind of shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it out. 'client' solved all my problems. This is the one that makes most sense for my use.